# How can I unserialize basic types and arrays secure?

Tags: php, security, serialization

I have to use unserialize with user-provided data in my project.
IFAIK, using unserialize with untrusted data is unsecure due to possibility of execute user code via implicit call of wakeup-function and destructor ( https://wiki.php.net/rfc/secure_unserialize ).

OK, I've tried smth like this

```
$a = serialize(array('a'=>'b', 'c'=>20));
unserialize($a, array('allowed_classes'=>false));
```

but unserialize ignores ALL data this way...

So, the question is:
how can I unserialize string contains the array(s) and basic datatypes (like ints, strings, bools and so on), but protect myself from unserialize the objects of undesired classes (and execute undesired code)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which version of PHP you are using but the second argument of `unserialize` is only available in PHP 7.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

> 7.0.0     The options parameter has been added.

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli):

```
php > $a = serialize(array('a'=>'b', 'c'=>20));
php > var_dump(unserialize($a, array('allowed_classes'=>false)));
PHP Warning:  unserialize() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0
PHP   2. unserialize() php shell code:1
bool(false)
```

PHP 7.0.12 (cli):

```
php > $a = serialize(array('a'=>'b', 'c'=>20));
php > var_dump(unserialize($a, array('allowed_classes'=>false)));
array(2) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "b"
  ["c"]=>
  int(20)
}
```

PHP 7.0.12 (cli) with a serialized object:

```
php > $a = serialize(array('a'=>'b', 'c'=>20, 'd'=> new Exception));
php > var_dump(unserialize($a, array('allowed_classes'=>false)));
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "b"
  ["c"]=>
  int(20)
  ["d"]=>
  object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (8) {
    ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=>
    string(9) "Exception"
    ["message":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["string":"Exception":private]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["code":protected]=>
    int(0)
    ["file":protected]=>
    string(14) "php shell code"
    ["line":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["trace":"Exception":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

I can't speak for it's security or completeness but [comment 119851](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php#119851) in the `unserialize` php docs gives this implmentation of `unserialize` with the options argument for > PHP 5.3:

```
function php7_unserialize($str, $options = array())
{
  if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.0.0', '>='))
  { return unserialize($str, $options); }

  $allowed_classes = isset($options['allowed_classes']) ?
    $options['allowed_classes'] : true;
  if(is_array($allowed_classes) || !$allowed_classes)
  {
    $str = preg_replace_callback(
      '/(?=^|:)(O|C):\d+:"([^"]*)":(\d+):{/',
      function($matches) use ($allowed_classes)
      {
        if(is_array($allowed_classes) &&
          in_array($matches[2], $allowed_classes))
        { return $matches[0]; }
        else
        {
          return $matches[1].':22:"__PHP_Incomplete_Class":'.
            ($matches[3] + 1).
            ':{s:27:"__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name";'.
            serialize($matches[2]);
        }
      },
      $str
    );
  }
  unset($allowed_classes);
  return unserialize($str);
}
```

Comment: yes, it was my mistake to use @unserialize, so I wasnt able to see this warning with PHP 5.3.

Comment: and thanks for the php7_unserialize implementation, it looks secure as far as I can see.